# Error while deploying Jersey REST on weblogic (<BEA-101216> <Servlet: "RestServlet" failed to preload on startup in Web application: "gateway".)

Tags: java, rest, jersey, weblogic, web-deployment

Not able to deploy jersey REST on weblogic server, is there any REST service configuration specific to weblogic ?

**Complete stacktrace -**

> 25 Apr, 2018 7:01:53 PM
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl initiate
>   INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.2 05/07/2010
>   02:11 PM' 25 Apr, 2018 7:01:53 PM
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl
>   processRootResources SEVERE: The ResourceConfig instance does not
>   contain any root resource classes. <25 Apr, 2018 7:01:53 PM IST>
>      (StubLifecycleHelper.java:48)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.prepareServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:539)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadServlet(WebAppServletContext.java:1981)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.loadServletsOnStartup(WebAppServletContext.java:1955)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1874)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3155)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1518)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:484)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:427)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:54)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedModuleDriver.java:201)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:249)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:427)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:54)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:28)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:672)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:54)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:212)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:59)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:161)
>     at
>   weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:79)
>     at
>   weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.activate(BasicDeployment.java:184)
>     at
>   weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.activateFromServerLifecycle(BasicDeployment.java:361)
>     at
>   weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter$1.doActivate(DeploymentAdapter.java:52)
>     at
>   weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter.activate(DeploymentAdapter.java:200)
>     at
>   weblogic.management.deploy.internal.AppTransition$2.transitionApp(AppTransition.java:31)
>     at
>   weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.transitionApps(ConfiguredDeployments.java:240)
>     at
>   weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.activate(ConfiguredDeployments.java:170)
>     at
>   weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.deploy(ConfiguredDeployments.java:124)
>     at
>   weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.resume(DeploymentServerService.java:181)
>     at
>   weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.start(DeploymentServerService.java:97)
>     at weblogic.t3.srvr.SubsystemRequest.run(SubsystemRequest.java:64)
>     at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)  at
>   weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)

**web.xml -**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
                         "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">
<web-app>
 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>FrontController</servlet-name>
  <display-name>FrontController</display-name>
  <description>Front Controller for handling requests</description>
  <servlet-class>com.obopay.icici.FrontController</servlet-class>
 </servlet>
 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>RestServlet</servlet-name>
  <display-name>RestServlet</display-name>
  <description>Rest Controller for handling http rest requests</description>
  <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
   <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
   <param-value>com.obopay.ebp.auth.resources</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>FrontController</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/siAuth</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>FrontController</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>FrontController</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/failureResponse</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>FrontController</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/successResponse</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>RestServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 <session-config>
  <session-timeout>5</session-timeout>
 </session-config>
 <!-- Define an error handler for 404 pages -->
 <error-page>
  <error-code>404</error-code>
  <location>/jsp/error.jsp</location>
 </error-page>
 <!-- Define an error handler for java.lang.Throwable -->
 <error-page>
  <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
  <location>/jsp/error.jsp</location>
 </error-page>
 <login-config>
  <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
 </login-config>
</web-app>
```

i am using the below **jars** -

```
jersey-bundle-1.2.jar
jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar
asm-3.1.jar
wlthint3client.jar
log4j-1.2.15.jar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved!

Problem was not with the weblogic server, the problem was, I had my source code in separate folder instead of src, so weblogic was not able to find package to scan in src folder, after adding below plugin in pom.xml, deployment was successful -

```
<plugin>
   <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.2</version>
   <executions>
      <execution>
         <id>copy-source</id>
         <phase>generate-sources</phase>
         <goals>
            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
         </goals>
         <configuration>
            <outputDirectory>co/src</outputDirectory>
            <overwrite>true</overwrite>
            <resources>
               <resource>
                  <directory>${basedir}/co/EBP</directory>
               </resource>
            </resources>
         </configuration>
      </execution>
   </executions>
</plugin>
```

This plugin copies my source code to src folder with overwrite as true. Hence made source code available in src folder.

This problem could also be resolved by adding source folder in .classpath file.